# RadioGroup selecionar item atraves de uma string

Tags: delphi

Tenho um radioGroup com os itens:

```
0 : bola
1 : futebol
2 : gol
3 : chuteira
4:  jogador
```

Como selecionar o Index através do valor gravado no banco que é "bola, futebol...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localize o Index através do `IndexOf`:

```
RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := RadioGroup1.Items.IndexOf('futebol');
```

Lembre que no Radio group somente uma opção ficará selecionada, se quiser selecionar mais de uma opção, use o `CheckListBox` da aba `Additional`.